# How I get the field value from an auto increment field

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [(mysql, php) How to get auto_increment field value before inserting data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251463/mysql-php-how-to-get-auto-increment-field-value-before-inserting-data)

I have this table which is for users. the `user_id` is an auto increment field. I'm using PDO to connect and execute to the database. How I can get the `user_id` value after adding a new user?

I've tried to user `mysql_insert_id()`, but nothing happened.

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO  `users` (`user_name` ,`user_password` ,) VALUES (?, ?)";

    $db = new DB; // create Database handler.       
    if($db->execute($sql,$this->name,$this->password))
    {
        $this->permission = new permission(mysql_insert_id()); // <--- HERE
        $this->permission->reset();
        $this->permission->insert();
    }
    return true;
```

because the new class will be constructed base on a `user_id` value. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I want the value after inserting the user, not before. I'm using PDO to connect with the database, so that's my problem.

Comment: You can just query the database on the username, which you already know. You DO check to make sure that username isn't taken, right?

Comment: @Greg after inserting the user I want to create a new class with the user permission in the script. In order to do it, I need the user ID to initialize the permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysql_insert_id() is not PDO.  Have you tried [$db->lastInsertId()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) after $db->execute?

Comment: Call to undefined method db::lastinsertid()

Comment: To my knowledge, thats part of the PDO Class.  Perhaps it's your choice of databases and the drivers it's using.  Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: e.g. , per the manual, "... depending on the underlying driver. For example, PDO_PGSQL() requires you to specify the name of a sequence object for the name parameter"

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch the recently added autoincrement ID by using following SELECT query:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```