# Php Mysql - Get value auto increment before and insert it to another column

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

I want insert some value to name column like

```
id|name
1 |1_myvalue
2 |2_myvalue
...
```

This table has **multi users can insert** to that. What can I do to make that thanks

```
$r = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `test`(`name`) VALUES ('_myvalue')");
```

Comment: auto increment value is generated only at the time of insert so you cannot get it before insert.but there is a workaround for you check this post [(mysql, php) How to get auto_increment field value before inserting data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251463/mysql-php-how-to-get-auto-increment-field-value-before-inserting-data)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251463/mysql-php-how-to-get-auto-increment-field-value-before-inserting-data

Comment: Save the record, get the inserted record's id, update it

Comment: There's no safe way to do it! The most you could do is obtaining the latest registered id by calling last_insert_id() + 1 and locking table before you record a new record.

Comment: Why is there no safe way to do it? there are many ways to do it

Comment: Do you really need to preprend the id to your value?  May be there are other better solutions to your problem than doing this?  May we know what your goal is?

Comment: @vinodadhikary I want store my upload file, Because the id is sole then the uploaded file will not coincidence

Comment: In either case, you would have to query this table before retrieving the file so why not concatenate `id` and `name` in select query and not bother with this insert? Possible?

Comment: @vinodadhikary b/c when a user upload a file I have to store the file in a folder and insert information to my table (MySQL).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple workaround:
Save the record, get the inserted record's id, update it to the proper value

```
$r = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `test`(`name`) VALUES ('myvalue')");
//1. save the record

$id=mysqli_insert_id($conn));
//2.  get it's id

mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE `test` set `name` = $id"."'_myvalue' where id=$id limit 1");
//3. update the record appending correct id to the value as desired
```

Comment: That's working But, if multi users insert at the same time or another way, is that correct?

Comment: Yes why not? for most of the active website where are always multiple users doing stuff at the same time, that doesn't confuse MySQL into believing things otherwise. Why complicate things

Comment: b/c I want store my upload file, and the id is sole then the uploaded file will not coincidence :) thanks u

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem