# best way to get the auto_incremented value of one table at the time of insertion

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, transactions, distributed-transactions

in my database there are three tables,they are

```
posts{ post_id , title , description ,etc ,etc}
tags{ tag_id , tag_name , tag_type }
tags_for_post{ tag_ref_id , post_ref_id}
```

so as you can see once i insert a row in `posts` table then i will need that row's `post_id` value to update my `tags_for_posts` table. that is,  which tags are tagged in which post are stored in `tags_for_posts` table and to do it i will need the corresponding posts `post_id` value.

so **my question is how will i get the auto incremented value(i.e. `post_id`) at the time of insertion???** but there is a problem

it will run on a server so multiple number of clients will access it at a same time.so it may happen that two clients  accessing the `posts` table at the same time. so how can i assure that the last_insert_id() will give the corresponding posts `post_id`.

**so i want do it in three steps like:**

1. enter few column's data in `posts` table and get the value of auto_incremented post_id value of this row
2. now use that row's `post_id` value for corresponding tag insertion in `tag_for_post` table.
3. again come to `posts` table complete rest calculations and updates.

as i said earlier the main problem which i encountered is how can i assure that i will always get the corresponding row's `post_id` value even if multiple clients accessing it at same time. **i dont think `mysql_insert_id` or `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will work for this purpose because multiple clients can try to insert at same time.so how can i assure that each time i will get the id of corresponding row**

now before marking it as duplicate thread, i want say i have searched a lot in google and stackoverflow and most of them advising to use `mysql_insert_id` or `LAST_INSERT_ID()` and as i said i am not happy with this because i think it wont give the desired result for multiple access at same time.

i have found two solutions which is likely to solve my problem [**using procedure**](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Return-Identity-Auto-Increment-Column-value-after-record-insert-in-SQL-Server-Database-using-ADONet-with-C-and-VBNet.aspx) and [**using transaction:stackoverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251463/mysql-php-how-to-get-auto-increment-field-value-before-inserting-data/2251486#2251486)

in stackoverflow solution they are saying to write the code as ::

```
begin transaction
insert into your table (half empty values);
$id = get last autoincrement id
do calculations
update set data = full data where id = $id
commit transaction
```

now my questions are ::

1. will the above code solve my problem properly??
2. will i need to write additional code for implementing the above code??
3. if the problem cant be solved using above code then how can i solve??
4. does the above code ensures that it will always return the corresponding `post_id` even in case of multiple insertion at same time.
5. **for example, assume that one client has issued an `inseret` command and before that client issues `$id = get last autoincrement id` another client has already issued `insert`command.now will the first client get the id of the row which he inserted using the above code??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last insert ID is unique to each client connected, it points to the last ID inserted by that client only, and not other IDs inserted by other clients.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a
>   per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the
>   function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated
>   for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that
>   client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they
>   generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures
>   that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the
>   activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or
>   transactions.

In other words you do not need to perform any kind of locking for this if you have multithreading in mind.

Comment: so what do u recommend?? using transaction is better approach or not??? or should i use that `last insert ID`??

Comment: and which is more safe to do it??

Comment: Getting the last insert ID is always safe, but if you need to update those two tables at the same time to prevent user error from accessing them while they are being worked on, then you need a transaction or lock.

Comment: will yp please elaborate??i said how i want to do it in three steps??now what do you recommend??can i use `last_insert_id()`with in a transaction??what are the disadvantage of using a transaction?