# Mysql column value to use increment id

Tags: mysql

If i have the following table structure:

```
id
name
account_id
```

account_id will always be a string of 6 characters Starting with a letter X and then padded with the increment id of the row.

Is there a way to do this with only 1 save of the row?

I am currently performing 2 saves: 1 to insert the name and generate the increment id and then another to grab the increment id and then save the account_id value.

Comment: Don't think you can do this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251463/mysql-php-how-to-get-auto-increment-field-value-before-inserting-data

Comment: Why store this at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use mysql v5.7.6 or newer, then you can define the account number as [generated column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

> As of MySQL 5.7.6, CREATE TABLE supports the specification of
>   generated columns. Values of a generated column are computed from an
>   expression included in the column definition.
>
> The following simple example shows a table that stores the lengths of
>   the sides of right triangles in the sidea and sideb columns, and
>   computes the length of the hypotenuse in sidec (the square root of the
>   sums of the squares of the other sides):
>
> `CREATE TABLE triangle (   sidea DOUBLE,   sideb DOUBLE,   sidec DOUBLE`
>   `AS (SQRT(sidea * sidea + sideb * sideb)) );`
>
> `INSERT INTO triangle (sidea, sideb) VALUES(1,1),(3,4),(6,8);`

In older versions you could omit the account number from the table definition and create a view on the top of the table that calculates account number on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

If we don't want to include it in business logic then I would suggest writing an [AFTER INSERT](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_insert.php) trigger and implement account id generation into it.

Here is an [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d97d/1) of After insert trigger which inserts a record into another table. We can probably write something similar to this.